# Making and Object uniteractable

Tags: object, unity-game-engine

So I have a part of my game where the character is selecting an area of the map. And it opening up a panel. I have made it so that happens but an=m now stuck on the other part of it. I want only certain area of the map to be intractable, so that I can bar the player from selecting areas of the map that they aren't ready for. I have no idea how to make game objects in the game uninteractable. I have looked on Stack overflow, Youtube an d the Unity API to no success. Can someone help me with that.

Comment: How is your map separated? How do you currently detect clicks o the map? Please update your question with these info. A screenshot of the map in the scene view would be helpful.

Comment: Can you describe how they're interacted with and how they should be handled when considered locked vs not locked?  Are these just `GameObjects` that the player clicks? Should they display something when they're locked and clicked or should they just be entirely ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to make things un-interactable will vary depending on your situation. I'll be presuming that you're map is broken up into a grid of sorts.

The basic setup would involve a bool, probably called 'CanAccessZone'. 
Then you'll need a class, to store any access info and popup logic, by popup logic I mean make the element either non-interactable or show a popup, with the shown popup being dependant on 'CanAccessZone'. This class can then be set up by your Map class when the level is loaded, or you could let the popup class grab the necessary values from the Map class.

If you're using Unity's UI buttons for the map pieces, then you could set interactable to false, until you want to let the player access the zone. If you want to display a popup informing the player that they can't access the zone, then your button will be interactable, but the click will delegate to your popup logic method.

It's a similiar principle if you're using gameobjects as buttons. You'd be using any of the OnMouse events to handle click events. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html

Hopefully this'll lead you in the right direction.